# Problem Saving and Loading Json file in Unity

Tags: json, unity-game-engine

I'm currently trying to use gestures recognizers in Unity3D. For this I need a library of gestures to be compared with the gesture I'm making.
I'm using a script to save and load from another Unity user since I have no idea how to do it myself.
The problem I'm facing is: 
If I save the gestures as json file during gameplay, I can compare them in the same run. But if I restart the run, it stops being able to read the json file and returns NULL or no match as if there were nothing in the json file.

```
[Serializable]
public class GestureTemplates
{
    public List<DrawnGesture> templates;

    public GestureTemplates()
    {
        templates = new List<DrawnGesture>();
    }

}
private string gestureFileName = "gestures.json";

void Start () {
        LoadTemplates();
}

private void SaveTemplates()
    {
        string filePath = Application.dataPath + "/streamingAssets/" + gestureFileName;
        string saveData = JsonUtility.ToJson(templates);
        File.WriteAllText(filePath, saveData);
        Debug.Log("Template Saved");
    }

    private void LoadTemplates()
    {
        templates = new GestureTemplates();
        string filePath = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, gestureFileName);
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            string data = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            templates = JsonUtility.FromJson<GestureTemplates>(data);
        }
    }
```

What I've noticed is it takes a while to save, but it does in fact save since it calls the debug.Log line and the save file can be used in the same run.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Edit: Nevermind. It's not saving either. It's saving as a Json file with an empty list. The variable is working on the run, but it's not saving nor loading.

Comment: Is `DrawnGesture` Serializable? I believe it must be Serializable too, not just `GestureTemplates`.

Comment: I think it's already serializable since the class is. I added SerializeField just to be sure and it is still not saving.

Comment: What I mean is, is the DrawnGesture class itself Serializable? IIRC Serializable classes can only JSON-save class properties that are themselves Serializable. For built-in Types, they’re Serializable by default, but I think you need to manually make custom classes Serializable.

Comment: Sorry! I misunderstood your point. Yes, it is already set to Serializable.
`
[Serializable]
public class DrawnGesture
{
    private TwoDPoint[] points;
    private string name;
    private float maxX;
    private float minX;
    private float maxY;
    private float minY;
    private int numPoints;
`

Comment: I already tried to iterate through the list and save item by item on it but it still returns blank:
"{templates:[],[],[]}

Comment: I managed to do it by serializing every variable one by one with SerializeField in Drawn Gesture. Even though the class was Serializable, for some reason, json could not save it.

Comment: You cannot save to streamingAssets, it's readonly.

Comment: Well, it is saving fine.